# Recover Bitcoin Cash from Multibit

Tags: multibit

I held Bitcoin in Multibit before the summer fork and later found that it wasn't supported anymore and installed Electrum. If I install Electroncash and use the same seed phrase, will I recover my Bitcoin Cash and should I also install Electroncash on a seperate machine to Electrum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the adress that the seed belongs to held any bitcoin at the time of the split, 
then yes,

BCH should have been credited to the adress with that seed phrase, since they use the same adress format.

For absolute security, yes, you should. See https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt

Comment: Have set up successfully on another machine but no BCH in wallet. Have followed the instructions on the following reddit strand but it hasn't worked (I selected cascharia as the server)  Problem is the strand below refers to Electron Cash 2.9.1 and I'm running 2.9.4. Any ideas? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62507/recover-bitcoin-cash-from-multibit

Comment: You can simply export the private key from Multibit and import it to Electrum Cash with the same private key. Goes for Bitcoin Gold , BSV etc. Dont use the seed, Electrum uses non BIP39 seed phrases